# Dictionary validation - program takes first input which may be wrong

Tags: python, validation, dictionary

```
while exit :
               try:
                   serialnumber = int(input("serial number of product :"))
               except ValueError :
                   print("Invalid input")
                   print()
               else:
                   if len(str(serialnumber)) == 6:
                       break
                   print()
                   print("Serial number cant be used, format : 012345 ")
                   print()
                   productserialnumber[item] = serialnumber
```

hi guys , so i have been trying to perform validation for this input and the input will be added to a dictionary. i managed to perform validation where if the value does not meet the requirements, the program will prompt the user again.

However, the program always takes the wrong input ( first input ) even though it reprompts the user for the correct input after the wrong input.

it doesnt not take the correct input instead it takes the first input which may be wrong.

i will appreciate any help i can get thanks alot

Comment: Is this your actual indentation? You execute the line `productserialnumber[item] = serialnumber` only when the `serialnumber` is incorrect. Also note that `len(str(012345))` is not equal to `6`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Store the value in dictionary only when condition is `True` your code is storing the value in dictionary even if the length not equal to 6.

Change this

```
if len(str(serialnumber)) == 6:
    break
productserialnumber[item] = serialnumber
```

this

```
if len(str(serialnumber)) == 6:
    productserialnumber[item] = serialnumber
    break
```